# Tool to capture all my travels?

Tags: maps, travel-tools

Is there a tool available where all my travel can be added to a map?

I'd like to find one so that I can track the time I spent on wheels or in the air and also see a nice display on a map of all the places that I have visited.

Comment: You want a website or an electronic device?

Answer (score 4):

A nice choice for this is [TripIt](https://www.tripit.com/). It's primary purpose is as an itinerary manager; once you sign up, you can forward flight, hotel, car rental etc. confirmation emails to them, and have it build these into a nice formatted itinerary for you.

However, this also has the nice side effect that all old itineraries are retained. It will build statistics out of this, showing you, for example:

- How many miles you have travelled in the year.
- How many trips you've done.
- How many countries/cities you have visited.

You can also build up a network of other contacts that use TripIt, seeing where they are, and have been, on a map. Plus, there is an iCal feed available, so you can see it in Google Calendar, for example.

I am a Pro member (which gets you extra features), but am otherwise unaffiliated with TripIt.

**Note**: [Dopplr](http://www.dopplr.com/) used to be in favor for this purpose, but it has grown stale and unmaintained in the last few years. Its features are mostly a subset of TripIt's.

**Update**: [Here's an example TripIt profile](https://www.tripit.com/people/andrewf) (mine, in fact) - to give you a flavor of the features.

Answer (score 3):

Below are a list of the various tools I use.  None of them will probably match exactly what you want, but the combination of will probably cover most of it - it does for me!

[FlightMemory](http://www.flightmemory.com) and [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/) - These tools are both designed to achieve basically the same thing - tracking all of the flights you've taken.  FlightMemory is older and whilst relatively basic still does a good job.  OpenFlights is newer and I've only played with it a little, but it does have features like being able to import flights directly from TripIt (see below!), although I haven't used that feature yet so I can't comment on how well it works. Both are free.

As an example, you can see my (somewhat outdated) Flight Memory output [here](http://my.flightmemory.com/doc). Interestingly their map doesn't show my trips to New Zealand - not sure why!

[TripIt](http://www.tripit.com) - TripIt is great for managing plans before and during your trip, although it also works well as a history of where you've been - however there are only very basic functionality for reporting on your history other than on a trip-by-trip basis.  TripIt is free, with a paid version available that adds additional features.

[EveryTrail](http://www.everytrail.com) - EveryTrail uses GPS tracks (or manually entered paths) to display where you've been.  It's mainly designed for activities like hiking, mountain biking, etc, however I've seen people upload much longer tracks for car trips/etc. You can also upload photos (or import them from Flickr or a few other sources), and EveryTrail will assign them to the exact point where they were taken (presuming your GPS/camera are in sync timewise).  EveryTrail is free.

You can see my profile and some sample entries on EveryTrail [here](http://www.everytrail.com/profile.php?user_id=269367).

Comment: Doc, re: TripIt - that's not quite correct - TripIt will show some aggregrate information on all your trips, including how many days you've spent, how many miles you've done, plotting them on a map, etc. But it is limited.

Answer (score 2):

[Everytrail](http://www.everytrail.com) is a good choice to record a trip and display it on a map and gives you the ability to add information in every point along with photos and other stuff.

From everytrail website:

> - Write guides and review trails you have done
> - Map a trip route with your phone or GPS
> - Add trip photos to your map instantly
> - Add maps & photos to your blog or website
> - Explore and share in the EveryTrail community